# How to install grub for a multiboot external hard drive

Tags: grub, external-hdd, multiboot

I have an external hard drive which contains three primary partitions, two of them with an Ubuntu flavor each (14.04, 16.04), and the third contains just data. There is also an extended partition with a Windows 7, another Ubuntu, and a Swap partition, each one with its own partition. The reason for this mess is basically me wanting to have bootable backups of older systems where some of my work resides. The partitions in the extended partition have been pasted from an internal drive (copy and paste through GParted). Now I would like to have GRUB in a such way that I can boot into any of the o.s.'s, if a need arises.

To install GRUB I have followed this post using a live USB: [How do I run update-grub from a LiveCD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145241/how-do-i-run-update-grub-from-a-livecd) I've installed it on the first primary partition which contains an Ubuntu 14.04.

The GParted view of the partitions in the external drive:

[image: The GParted view of the partitions in the external drive]

What happens when I follow these steps is that the GRUB listings contain also the bootable partitions from the internal drive. If I let it boot from the default listing (the first in the list) it will give the error below, but still boots. If I try any other listing again, it gives the same error as below:

```
attempt to read or write outside of disk hd0.
press any key to continue.
```

After pressing a key, it returns to boot menu, and won't even boot from default listing.

Any insights of what could be going wrong or what I could try?
What I want is to have GRUB installed in external drive, showing listings based only on bootable partitions of that external drive.

UPDATE 1:

The `blkid` gives the following:
[blkid_out](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZMpYuN_qllNm9BRc94GUd9l70cZz1n8K/view?usp=sharing)

The contents of the `grub.cfg` file:
[grub.cfg](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dWVYM3v-DXt2BFlQm-eO7MqaJ4fcnTKy/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` by hand. It is a normal text file. Remove the entries you do not want. Be sure you pick the `grub.cfg` on the partition you had mounted when you ran `update-grub`.

Comment: Ok, I will try this today.

Comment: I could get rid of extra entries by modifying the grub.cfg. However the problem from before, when I try to boot any of the rest, persists, i.e, "attempt to read or write outside of disk hd0. press any key to continue", also "no device found <name here>". So somehow it is not finding the device or partitions. Any idea? and thanks for your help :).

Comment: I misunderstood that portion of your question. Sorry. I recommend this procedure: Download the [Super GRUB2 disk](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub2-disk/) and install it to a flash drive. Use it to boot into one of the Ubuntu installations on the external drive. Invoke `update-grub` (and `grub-install`, if necessary) from within the booted system. Using another drive is a bit cumbersome, but I observed this method to be more reliable.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, I will give this a go!

Comment: Hej I tried this, and when I select some entries I get the same message as before, in one case I get the grub prompt.

Comment: Looks like a more delicate problem. Please add the `grub.cfg` used for booting and the output of `blkid` (run from the live system is sufficient) to your question.

Comment: Hej, I have updated the answer. If you have any further insight it'd be of help!

Comment: The files are looking good. I am afraid, I cannot see what is wrong.

Comment: Aha, then maybe I should try booting into it from another machine. Thank you for your effort!